# __dirname is not defined within API routes

Tags: next.js

I have a Next.js API route which needs to access a local file, but __dirname is not defined when I use it within an API route.

Is it possible to get the current directory from within a Next route?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that works in production?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js: How to get static assets from within getStaticProps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65861629/1870780)? Use `process.cwd()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the root directory, or any directory for that matter, you can used `next.config.js` to set a webpack alias. Example:

```
// Inside next.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      '~': __dirname,
    };
  }
```

Now `~`, when used to path to resources, will resolve to the value of `__dirname`.

Alternatively you could use next.js's client env if you're on next.js 8+. Example:

```
// inside next.config.js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    ROOT: __dirname,
  }
}
```

Now using `process.env.ROOT` gives you access to `__dirname`.

Comment: Is there any solution for prod?