# Next.js: How to get static assets from within getStaticProps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, netlify-cms

I am using Netlify CMS. I want to import all the slides for a carousel into my component. I made a collection called slider and added a few slides. That created two markdown files (one for each slide) in `public/content/slider/`. I would like to import them all into an iteratable object so I can build the carousel.

Because I have a webpack loader set up for markdown files, I can import a single markdown file no problem, like this:

`import post from '../public/content/posts/[post name].md`

But when I try to use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext), [require-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-context), or import `fs`, it's no good. So I decide to try requiring those libs from within `getStaticProps`. But `__dirname` in `getStaticProps` is `/`, the root of my computer's filesystem.

All the `getStaticProps` examples use data fetching. I'm missing some info. How can I import all the markdown files in the `/slides/` folder?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a known issue in Next.js (see related discussion [#32236](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32236)), `__dirname` incorrectly resolves to `/` - you should use `process.cwd()` instead.

From the Next.js [Reading files](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#reading-files-use-processcwd) documentation:

> Files can be read directly from the filesystem in `getStaticProps`.
>
> In order to do so you have to get the full path to a file.
>
> Since Next.js compiles your code into a separate directory you can't
> use `__dirname` as the path it will return will be different from the
> pages directory.
>
> Instead you can use `process.cwd()` which gives you the directory where
> Next.js is being executed.