# Nodemailer with Next.js

Tags: next.js, nodemailer

Hello I'm using nodemailer with next, I'm trying to include an image in the email but keep getting this error

```
err: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/images/welcome.png'] {
    errno: -2,
    code: 'ESTREAM',
    syscall: 'open',
    path: '/images/welcome.png',
    command: 'API'
  }
```

any idea how can I successfully include image in one the Next /api routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to find the image directory from the root of the project instead that use like this

```
path: path.join(process.cwd(), `../static/images/your_image.png`)
```

Comment: You may need to use [`process.cwd()` rather than `__dirname`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65861629/1870780) in Next.js.

Comment: process.cwd() worked for me, thanks guys.