# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/google-cloud-key.json' Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

Please help me to solve..

My `JS file` file is in `Next JS app > pages/api/profile` and `google-cloud-key.json` is in Next JS app root folder itself where package.json is there.

Everything works fine in local, but below error given at Vercel

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/google-cloud-key.json' vercel
```

My google-cloud-key.json is in the root directory of next JS app.

I have tried below code also:

```
const storage = new Storage({
            projectId: 'careful-relic-319511',
            keyFilename: __dirname + '/../../../google-cloud-key.json'
        });
```

This is giving below error now:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/.next/server/google-cloud-key.json'] {\n  errno: -2,\n  code: 'ENOENT',\n  syscall: 'open',\n  path: '/var/task/.next/server/google-cloud-key.json'\n}\nEND
```

Comment: You can import JSON normally like, `const data = await import('../data.json')`.

Comment: Try [using `process.cwd()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65861629/1870780) instead of `__dirname`.

Answer (score 2):

Hey i found a great solution

1. Base64 encode the json file. (https://www.base64encode.org/)
2. Set an env variable (both in local and vercel setting) this encoded string. (In my case GCP_CRED_FILE)
3. 

```
const gcsKey = JSON.parse(
  Buffer.from(process.env.GCP_CRED_FILE, 'base64').toString()
);

const storage = new Storage({
  credentials: {
    client_email: gcsKey.client_email,
    private_key: gcsKey.private_key
  },
  projectId: gcsKey.project_id
});
```

this works for me. tested using nextjs 11 and vercel deployments

Moreover you dont need to store or push the file to a repo or store it (which can be a security threat)

Comment: Thank you! This didn't solved reading the file from the filesystem at Vercel. But it did provide a good alternative solution that worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different and easy solution -

1. configure your credentials in next.config.js file -

```
const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    privateKey:
      "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nasdfdasfasdf=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    clientEmail: "your-client-email",
    projectID: 'your-project-id'
  },
 
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

2. use required credentials like -

```
const storage = new Storage({
  credentials: {
    client_email: process.env.clientEmail,
    private_key: process.env.privateKey
  },
  projectId: process.env.projectID
});
```

3. And Deploy. Setting environment variable in next.config.js file gives a benefit like you don't have to set variables in vercel. During build time, the required variables are pushed into codes. More information on how to use nextjs environment variables is [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/env)